# Angular get data from service with observable

Tags: angular

Using angular, I have a grid where user selects the data by clicking on the checkbox. I store the selection in an array.

Below is the code of selecting checbox

```
getCheckedItemList() {
  let selectedData: any[];

 //loop through array of data, find selected and populate selectedData array.

 //Below line sets selected data to the service
  this.myService.setSelectedData(this.selectedData); 

}
```

And below is the service as:

```
  export class MyService {
  public selectedData = new Subject<any[]>();
  public selectedDataObservable = this.selectedData.asObservable();

  setSelectedData(data: any[]) {    
    this.selectedData.next(data);    
  }
}
```

The above code all works fine.

The problem I am having is how to get this saved data from my service.

I tried to do something like:

```
 this.myService.selectedData
```

But this does not work.

Could anyone point how can I get the data?

Thanks

Comment: You have `selectedDataObservable` in the service. Subscribe to it in your component.

Comment: Is there any other way other than subscribing

Comment: apparently subscribing in your component is a bad thing these days. you should use the `async` pipe. and keep your component free of subscriptions.

Comment: @Stavm can you give example of how to do so

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change your service to use BehaviorSubject as

```
 export class MyService {
 public selectedData = new BehaviorSubject<any>();
 public selectedDataObservable = this.selectedData.asObservable();

 setSelectedData(data: any[]) {    
    this.selectedData .next(data);    
  }
}
```

And you can get this value as:

```
this.myService.selectedData.value
```